Trouble maintaining camera connection to network in station mode
I have a camera that I am using in station mode that can't seem to keep a stable connection to network A. I've tried other cameras in station mode to this network and they have worked just fine. I've also attempted to use this camera in station mode with my mobile hotspot and another network, network B. The camera ended up working fine with the mobile hotspot and network B, with no issues whatsoever. It seems like this issue only comes up with network A.
I normally use the Advanced IP scanner to search for the devices IP address. Sometimes its status shows as connected, other times it doesn't. It's very random when it actually is able to connect. Then I use VLC media player to open the camera, and when the camera IP address status isn't connected then we obviously do not get a video feed from the camera.
Are there any troubleshooting methods, or tools, that I could use to test my network or my device to narrow down what exactly is not allowing me to use this camera with network A?
Edit: I'm not sure if this was the right place post this, if it's not please let me know what stack exchange I should post this to.
